# how to handle "keytool error: java.io.IOException: Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect"

Tags: java, eclipse, ssl-certificate, keystore

I am importing keystore in java eclipse, so i am doing something like this

```
keytool -import -alias ndml -file kra.ndml.in.crt -keystore /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/security/cacerts
```

then it asks me to enter `Enter keystore password:` so after entering password, it gives me following error

```
keytool error: java.io.IOException: Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect
```

i am entering correct password, but i don't know why this error is coming.

Comment: if its in your hand try delete existing keystore file  create new keystore and  and import it again

Comment: if you have multiple jdk version in your machine give complete path for the keytool. Are you giving correct password for keytool. Default one is changeit i guess

Comment: The password would be by default 'changeit'